# AS3 - BitmapData FloodFill smooth

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, bitmapdata

I trying to do a floodfill with tolerance.

So I trying a solution, maybe get the color of floodfill, make another bitmap and aply a blur 
and draw over the first bitmapdata.
But I don't know how made this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you encountering? What issues does your current solution have?

Comment: It seems a problem with anti-alias to me. In this case it is hard to achieve good results with just floodfill. You may want to use a transparent image (e.g.: 24bits png) to have a template. Describe better your scenario so we can help you further...

Comment: exactly my problem antialias

Comment: something like that question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552335/soft-paint-bucket-fill-colour-equality

but I could get the answers working
Could you help me with a sample ?